# If one is in a hall of mirrors, at a carnival for example, would this sentence make sense, or is kaleidoscope incorrect (Also Me's?)

Tags: word-choice, thriller, flash-fiction

I have this sentence in a flash fiction. My alpha/beta readers are unsure if the wording is correct, and I am starting to doubt myself.

> As I entered, I picked a mirror ahead of me and locked eyes with my reflection, ignoring the infinite kaleidoscope of me’s beyond.

Is there a better way to describe this?

Comment: Ehh, it's a bit of a mixed message. Narrator is doing a concentrate, steady thing, while something dazzling is in the periphery being ignored – the sentence is backwards. First the dazzle that distracts, then concentrate to block it out, and focus on the eyes… the 'image' gets big to small.

Comment: So something like:

As I entered, I picked a mirror ahead of me, ignoring the infinite kaleidoscope of me's beyond, and locked eyes with my reflection.

Comment: You show us 1 mirror, then lots of mirrors, then eyes. I am suggesting a better order is to walk in, see lots of mirrors, focus on one mirror, then the eyes. Big thing, medium-sized thing, small thing. there is logic to it, my attention focuses like the protagonist = empathy. 

What you wrote makes me focus on mirror (medium), then many mirrors (large room), then eyes (narrow vision): this is scattering my attention. You've lead me from 1 mirror to many, but that's wrong because you want me to ignore it. It's a confused sequence of images.

Comment: @wetcircuit think the confusion lays in context, there is a very important plot point that involves not looking away from their reflection. Therefore I feel that they need to have that medium thing first, as it is the immediate thought/action. Having:
"As I entered, ignoring the kaleidoscope of me's beyond, I picked a mirror ahead of me and locked eyes with my reflection."
seems kind of round-about, and doesn't convey how the character feels as well. They are wary, maybe even a little scared.

Comment: The question of how to pluralize "me" was asked and answered on ELU: [Is "mes" an accepted plural form of "me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/246870/191178)

Comment: 'Mes' doesn't make any sense as a plural. At best it is confusing to the reader. The image described is not of several different people anyway. It is a image of the one me repeated. I would simply say 'kaleidoscope of me' and not try to pluralize something that isn't actually plural.

Answer (score 1):

The plural of me is accepted as *mes*.

I suggest changing one of the uses of *me*, however, as the repetition may sound jarring to some readers. Of course, from a structural perspective, the narrator is seeing an infinity of their image so one could argue that the multiple *mes* makes sense metafictionally.

Perhaps

> As I entered, I picked a mirror and locked eyes with my reflection ahead, ignoring the infinite kaleidoscope of mes beyond.

achieves the same for you?

Comment: I agree, I'd skip "mes" altogether. *"I picked a mirror and locked eyes with my reflection, ignoring the infinite kaleidoscope of my other reflections beyond."*

Answer (score 0):

Academically the experience of a House of Mirrors effect is not a Kaleidoscope effect (which creates symmetrical patterns).  A House of Mirrors is designed to trick someone within from finding the true path by the use of multiple mirrors and transparent and opaque walls to obscure the location of the correct path out of the maze (Often they are not even mazes... but labyrinths.  The difference is that in Labyrinths there is a single unbroken path to the center, such that as long as you move forward, you will reach the center.  A maze is a series of broken paths that may never lead to the center and your initial path may terminate in a dead end).

However, in this situation, it's purely being academic and this is perfectly fine if the speaker would not know this.

It would be correct to use the phrase "A kaleidoscope of me" as the word "Me" is the first person singular predicate pronoun.   The First Person plural predicate pronoun is "us".  By definition, there can never be more than one first person singular (even in a situation where you and your clone are interacting, your clone is their own unique person and thus would not be covered by your use of "me".... but would be covered under a use of "us").